# ID3D10Device creation failure in release mode

Tags: c++, directx

My ID3D10Device creation works fine in debug mode but I throws an error in release mode:

```
DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scDesc = {0};
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Width = desc.width;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Height = desc.height;
    /*scDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 60;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 1;*/
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;

    scDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    scDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    scDesc.OutputWindow = desc.hWnd;
    scDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    scDesc.Flags = 0;

    scDesc.Windowed = true;
    scDesc.SampleDesc.Count = desc.sampleCount;
    scDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = desc.sampleQuality;

    // Create the device.
    UINT createDeviceFlags = 0;
#if defined(DEBUG) || defined(_DEBUG)
    createDeviceFlags |= D3D10_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG;
#endif

    HRESULT hr;
    hr = D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        nullptr,
        D3D10_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        createDeviceFlags,
        D3D10_SDK_VERSION,
        &scDesc,
        &g_Renderer.m_DxCore.pSwapChain,
        &g_Renderer.m_DxCore.pDevice);

    std::tcout<<hr;


//////RUNTIME ERROR HANDLING
    if(FAILED(hr)) {
        throw std::runtime_error("ERROR: Failed to create ID3D10Device and IDXGISwapChain");
    }
```

I've already checked each of these options, but none of it triggers.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205278(v=vs.85).aspx

The value of the hr seems to be -2005270527, after checking it with `std::cout<<hr`
My debugger also can't show the value of hr when hovering over it, for some reason. :(

What could the problem possibly be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error code translates into DXGI_ERROR_INVALID_CALL. A likely reason for that error is an invalid (or zero) window handle being passed in the `OutputWindow` parameter. Could you check that it is properly set in your release mode run?

Comment: It is not properly set. If I set a breakpoint at `scDesc.BufferDesc.Height = desc.height;` it will stop there, but when I tell my debugger to go to the next statement (step over or F10 in Visual studio), the code seems to jump straight to `D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain()`, and if I check for the values of the description it didn't adjust the values I told it to either. How is that even possible?

Comment: @xcrypt: Not running the latest build by accident? I've done that a few times.

Comment: I finally found my error! The reason was I did ASSERT(RegisterClass(myWndClass)); Ofcourse that's going to fail in release mode... stupid me!

Comment: That's classic! Good job figuring it out!

Answer (score 1):

You're not supposed to specify a refresh rate when the device is windowed.

Comment: That shouldn't cause failure (they get ignored)

Comment: I tried this, still have the error

Answer (score 1):

Release mode runtime won't zero out allocations if I recall correctly, perhaps some of the parameters in scDesc are junk values that now need initializing.

Comment: This is probably it. In your declaration you should always use something like `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scDesc = { 0 } ;` so that the structure begins 0'd out.

Comment: I tried this, still have the error